# Possibility of R-Si-OCH3 reacting with alkanol group in polysaccharides

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, carbohydrates

For example, the aminosilanizing agent 3-aminopropyltriethoxysilane (APTES)

[image]

It has been frequently used for silanization of silica or glasses for various purposes. The surface funcation group of silica contain Si-OH which will react with APTES under certain conditions:

[image]

Both Si and C are group 4 elements
R-C-OH where the C-OH is less polar than Si-OH bond
Take glucose as the example, it contains 5 external C-OH bonds. So is it possible for APTES to react with glucose? If yes, what condition should it be?